# How to add a query parameter to the URL with react router v3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've just converted my application over to React with Redux and on one page I'm creating an item. Instead of opting for a save button I'm just going to automatically save the item when the user stops typing. The problem I have is that if they refresh the page, I want the application to be able to get the item the user created instead of a blank one.

The way I want to be able to handle this occurrence is to add the ID as a query parameter to the URL so when they refresh I know what item to fetch from the API.

How would I add a query parameter to the URL in a react/redux/react-router application?

I want something like `website.com/create-item?id=1234`

Comment: DId you manage to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In react-router V4 how can I programmatically set the query string params?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133994/in-react-router-v4-how-can-i-programmatically-set-the-query-string-params)

Comment: @PaulSweatte This question was for V3. V4 hadn't been released at the time so it can't possibly be a duplicate. I've updated the title to specify v3 due to API differences