# In react-router V4 how can I programmatically set the query string params?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Same question as here, but for react-router version 4.

[How do you programmatically update query params in react-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161516/how-do-you-programmatically-update-query-params-in-react-router)

This will probably be closed because I don't have any code to show, but at github they say "ask on Stack Overflow", and it's not in the documentation as far as I can see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44108850/adding-query-parameters-on-form-submission-react-router-4/44108971#44108971

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [withRouter higher order component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) to access the history directly.

e.g.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

class MyComp extends Component {
  doStuff = () => {
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/pathname',
      search: '?stuff=done'
    })
  }

  render () {
    <button onClick={this.doStuff}>Do stuff</button>
  }
}

export default withRouter(MyComp)
```